# How to fetch data from remote oracle database Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle

I want to fetch data from a remote Oracle database and display it on my web page how do i do that ?

despite i have successfully connected to the remote database by modifying the database.yml and using SQL developer to test out the connection.

Ruby version :2.6.5
Rails version : 6.0.2.1
database version: 19c

*
I have oracle instant client setup as well as the oracle gem and i can connect to the remote database however i still can't fetch data from the remote DB

**Due to this error**

Puma caught this error: '{ development => }' is not a valid configuration. Expected '' to be a URL string or a Hash. (ActiveRecord::DatabaseConfigurations::InvalidConfigurationError)

**my database.yml**

**default: &default**

adapter: oracle_enhanced

pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

host: link to server

database: dbname

username: dbuser

password: dbpass

port: portnum

**development:**

adapter: oracle_enhanced

username: dbuser

password: dbpass

database: serverlink/dbname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Oracle Instant Client and Ruby-OCI8

Install ActiveRecord oracle_enhanced adapter (version 1.3.1 is recommended)
gem install activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter

Replace the development section in the file config/database.yml with the following content and then save and close the file.

```
development:
    adapter: oracle_enhanced
    username: rubyhol
    password: welcome
    database: localhost/orcl
```

For more details follow this link: https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/oow10/rubyhol/instructions/rubyrails.htm